# What is the proper name for the ?? operator?

Tags: c#, operators

I had a look on MSDN but they don't seem to refer to it by name.

What's the official name for the `??` operator?

Comment: Just for future reference - [C# Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx)

Comment: Obviously not in the right place. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: First search result on MSDN for ['C# ??-Operator'](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=C%23%20%3F%3F-Operator&ac=8)

Comment: I was looking here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173224%28v=vs.80%29.aspx I didn't notice I was looking at 2005 at the time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's called the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

It is called [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173224%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Look at The [C# ?? null coalescing operator](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/20/the-new-c-null-coalescing-operator-and-using-it-with-linq.aspx) from Scott Guthrie.

> One of the subtle language features of C# is the **??** "null coalescing"
>   operator.  This provides a nice, terse way to check whether a value is
>   null, and if so return an alternate value.

Comment: @Nile: This was posted mere *seconds* after the previous answers. The site doesn't update with answers immediately, so you can't expect him to know other people posted answers within the same minute.

Comment: @BoltClock: A div pops up saying "... answers have been posted, reload." And besides, regardless of type-time, it's still useless to have duplicates.

Comment: @Nile: That does not happen *immediately*. There's such a thing as latency. And ideally each duplicate answer will be removed voluntarily by the author to reduce clutter, but that's not compulsory. But that's not my point... my point is that it's not he's not going to be able to read the other answers when they don't show up immediately in the first place.

Comment: @BoltClock: It (crossout: is) was still a duplicate, though I see an edit has been made.

Comment: @Nile In the past, I was thinking exactly like you http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94004/same-answers-should-be-deleted-in-stack-overflow

Answer (score 4):

The operator `??` is called [**null-coalescing operator**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)